# Looking for a PHP/Ajax/MySQL code snippet to add/edit tags - same as stackOverflow

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm in the middle of adding a tagging system to my website. I want to be able to easily add/edit items tags.

My current tags table structure is:

```
Table: Item
Columns: ItemID, Title, Content

Table: Tag
Columns: TagID, Title, Tag_Counter

Table: ItemTag
Columns: ItemID, TagID
```

I really like the implementation of the tagging in StackOverflow, can anyone direct me a code snippet I can use (PHP/Ajax/MySQL)?

I know, its a tough one...

Thanks,

Roy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to code it all by hand, you could try an open source solution.

For example, 
https://code.google.com/p/phptagengine/

If you want something more powerful that integrates with Flicker, Technorati, Delicious, etc the ZEND_Service framework has some pretty cool libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link for a script like you want exactly....

http://www.amitpatil.me/facebook-style-add-friends-script/

Enjoy!!